# Json parsing gives NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, gson

I am calling this url

> > http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=18.550455,73.920148&sensor=true

And getting a response (I have deleted a lot of the response from the middle since its not relevant for the question.

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Towards Wadgao Sheri",
               "short_name" : "Towards Wadgao Sheri",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "411014",
               "short_name" : "411014",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Towards Wadgao Sheri, Sainikwadi, Wadgaon Sheri, Pune, Maharashtra 411014, India",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 18.55131630,
                  "lng" : 73.91882219999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 18.55024130,
                  "lng" : 73.91866569999999
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 18.55077720,
               "lng" : 73.91878240
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 18.55212778029150,
                  "lng" : 73.92009293029150
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 18.54942981970850,
                  "lng" : 73.91739496970848
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "route" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Sainikwadi",
               "short_name" : "Sainikwadi",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "411014",
               "short_name" : "411014",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Sainikwadi, Wadgaon Sheri, Pune, Maharashtra 411014, India",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 18.5551140,
                  "lng" : 73.92143690
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 18.5465270,
                  "lng" : 73.91406809999999
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 18.55092520,
               "lng" : 73.91687659999999
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 18.5551140,
                  "lng" : 73.92143690
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 18.5465270,
                  "lng" : 73.91406809999999
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "India",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 35.50447520,
                  "lng" : 97.3955550
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 6.747138899999999,
                  "lng" : 68.16238590
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 20.5936840,
               "lng" : 78.962880
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 35.50447520,
                  "lng" : 97.3955550
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 6.747138899999999,
                  "lng" : 68.16279560
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Code

```
        JsonObject response = new JsonObject().getAsJsonObject(jsonResults.toString());
>>>NPE  JsonArray results = response.getAsJsonArray("results");
```

The response from json is in jsonResults. I am getting a NPE on the 2nd line

I guess response is null, I wonder why, what am doing wrong here ? Just created a json object out of the response json. I know I am missing something really silly here.

Edit :

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mcruiseon.ivr.God.getGeoAddress(God.java:141)
```

Edit 2 :

I have edited the json response a bit. Please note. Also I am trying to extract **formatted_address**

Edit 3 :

```
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
```

Comment: Please review my question again, changes to json and clear mention of imports used.  I am trying to keep the question very specific

Comment: can you post a valid json by checking @ http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: done, I have added a valid json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key to the answer : Gson or not, parsing the json string is the key to the answer.

From the comments by Siddharth below.

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject json = parser.parse(jsonResults.toString()).getAsJsonObject() ; 
JsonArray results = json.getAsJsonArray("results");
JsonObject result = results.get(0).getAsJsonObject(); 
customerAddress = result.get("formatted_address").getAsString();
```

Alternative :

I failed to read the edit 3 part of the question and failed to look at the `gson` tag. So i ended up providing the below alternative.

```
JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject (myjsonstring);
JSONArray myListsAll= new JSONArray(jsono.getString("results"));
for(int i=0;i<myListsAll.length();i++){
JSONObject jsonObject1 = (JSONObject) myListsAll.get(i);
JSONArray myarray= new JSONArray(jsonObject1.getString("address_components"));
for(int i1=0;i1<myarray.length();i1++)
{
JSONObject jsonobject2 =  myarray.getJSONObject(i1);                     
System.out.println(""+jsonobject2.getString("long_name"));                  
System.out.println(""+jsonobject2.getString("short_name"));
System.out.println(""+jsonobject2.getString("types"));
}
}
```

Output

```
Towards Wadgao Sheri
Towards Wadgao Sheri
["route"]
Sainikwadi
Sainikwadi
["neighborhood","political"]
Wadgaon Sheri
Wadgaon Sheri
["sublocality","political"]
Pune
Pune
 ["locality","political"]
 Pune
 Pune
 ["administrative_area_level_2","political"]
Maharashtra
MH
["administrative_area_level_1","political"]
India
IN
["country","political"]
411014
411014
["postal_code"]
 Sainikwadi
 Sainikwadi
 ["neighborhood","political"]
 Wadgaon Sheri
 Wadgaon Sheri
 ["sublocality","political"]
 Pune
 Pune
 ["locality","political"]
 Pune
 Pune
 ["administrative_area_level_2","political"]
 Maharashtra
 MH
 ["administrative_area_level_1","political"]
 India
 IN
 ["country","political"]
 411014
 411014
 ["postal_code"]
 Wadgaon Sheri
 Wadgaon Sheri
 ["sublocality","political"]
 Pune
 Pune
 ["locality","political"]
 Pune
 Pune
 ["administrative_area_level_2","political"]
 Maharashtra
 MH
 ["administrative_area_level_1","political"]
 India
 IN
 ["country","political"]
 411014
 411014
 ["postal_code"]
 Pune
 Pune
 ["administrative_area_level_2","political"]
 Maharashtra
 MH
 ["administrative_area_level_1","political"]
 India
 IN
 ["country","political"]
 Pune
 Pune
 ["locality","political"]
 Pune
 Pune
 ["administrative_area_level_2","political"]
 Maharashtra
 MH
 ["administrative_area_level_1","political"]
 India
 IN
 ["country","political"]
 Pune
 Pune
 ["administrative_area_level_2","political"]
 Maharashtra
 MH
 ["administrative_area_level_1","political"]
 India
 IN
 ["country","political"]
 Maharashtra
 MH
 ["administrative_area_level_1","political"]
 India
 IN
 ["country","political"]
 India
 IN
 ["country","political"]
```

Comment: I am using gson, it does not have JSONObject, instead has JsonObject. but I think I get the trick. I am not `parsing` it as you have are

Comment: i am not using any gson. i am using just jsonobject build in class

Comment: @Siddharth title got my confused and also i din't read edit 3 while posting the answer and also failed to look at the tag gson. could you consider using the above instead of gson?

Comment: nope i need to use gson. Lets do this instead. Just add the following to your answer so that I can keep my question clean. I give you that benefit since you gave me the hint to "parse" first. Thanks.  JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
  JsonObject json = parser.parse(jsonResults.toString()).getAsJsonObject() ;
  JsonArray results = json.getAsJsonArray("results");
  JsonObject result = results.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
  customerAddress = result.get("formatted_address").getAsString();

Comment: @Siddharth if it works edit my answer and post the same. you can put my answer under alternative section.

Comment: @Siddharth i did put the code in the comments as part of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You start off with ...

```
JsonObject response = new JsonObject().getAsJsonObject(jsonResults.toString());
```

This makes no sense. You've created a new, empty `JsonObject` then attempt to retrieve an element from it using your entire JSON string as the property name. Therefore, yes ... `response` is `null`.

Your JSON is an object. It contains two fields; `results` which is an array of objects and `status` which is a `String`.

Normally when using Gson you'd create matching Java classes and use a `Gson` instance to deserialize to them. If you don't want to do that, then you'd Gson's `JsonParser` to parse the Json and then access it through the various Json* classes:

```
/// jsonResuts is a String containing the JSON you list.
JsonObject obj = new JsonParser().parse(jsonResults).getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray resultsArray = obj.getAsJsonArray("results");
```

Now you have the array of objects and can delve deeper into that using the same methods/classes from Gson I used above.

```
for (JsonElement e : resultsArray) {
    JsonObject resultsObj = e.getAsJsonObject();
    JsonElement formattedAddress = resultsObject.get("formatted_address");
    String addressAsString = formattedAddress.getAsString();
    System.out.println(addressAsString);
    // The above can be chained and reduced to one line:
    // System.out.println(e.getAsJsonObject().get("formatted_address").getAsString());
}
```

Comment: You are right. I am tempted to accept your answer. I have already fixed it after reviewing @Raghunandan's answer. Thanks again. This answer is good.